# Declaring a new object and calling some of its methods on creation

Tags: java, declaration

I happened about this declaration on the internet and found it really interesting.
However I don't know what to search for to get more information about it.
If you could tell me a bit about this or what to search for...

(the calling of methods on declaration)

```
 JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel(){{
        setBackground(Color.blue);
        setLocation(220, 10);
        setSize(50, 50);
 }};
```

Comment: `setLocation(220, 10);
        setSize(50, 50);`  Lose whatever you found.  It is rubbish code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're deriving an anonymous subclass of `JPanel` and then declaring a *initialiser block* for it.

Here's the subclass:

```
new JPanel(){};
```

Note the braces. And the initaliser is declared within it:

```
new JPanel() {
 { 
    // static initaliser
 }
};
```

The derivation of a subclass is simply to allow the initialiser block. This is called *double-brace initialisation*, and some worry about the abuse of creating an anonymous class simply for this purpose.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for more info about the initialiser block.